# Is it possible to specify Mongo text search delimiters?

Tags: mongodb

**Problem Synopsis**

I'm looking to return the best matched Mongo document from a collection that contains roughly 10 million entries. I have a text index on the collection spanning multiple fields (firstName, lastName, id, etc.). The id's take the form of `#-###-###`.

I've found that when specifying an exact phrase for these id's, `${search: '"1-234-567"'}`, I do receive the correct document back, but not without a large performance hit of about 60+ seconds. On the other hand, if I remove the hyphens for my search, `${search: '"1234567"'}`, the result comes back instantly.

**Diagnosis**

I believe this occurs because Mongo is delimiting my query by hyphens (even though the phrase is quoted) and perhaps a second filter is ensuring I only get an exact match. This seems to be proved out by query explains:

*Hyphenated Search*

```
db.person.find({$text: {$search: '"1-234-567"'}}, { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }).limit(1).sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } }).explain()
{
        ...
                        "indexName" : "Person_TextIndex",
                        "parsedTextQuery" : {
                            "terms" : [
                                "1",
                                "234",
                                "567"
                            ],
                            "negatedTerms" : [ ],
                            "phrases" : [
                                "1-234-567"
                            ],
                            "negatedPhrases" : [ ]
                        },
        ...
}
```

*Non-Hyphenated Search*

```
db.person.find({$text: {$search: '"1234567"'}}, { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }).limit(1).sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } }).explain()
{
        ...
                        "indexName" : "Person_TextIndex",
                        "parsedTextQuery" : {
                            "terms" : [
                                "1234567"
                            ],
                            "negatedTerms" : [ ],
                            "phrases" : [
                                "1234567"
                            ],
                            "negatedPhrases" : [ ]
                        },
        ...
}
```

**Notice the terms array on the hyphenated search.** I believe this will sift through documents matching "1", "234", "567" before ultimately giving me the correct document(s).

**Potential Solutions**

I can't really put a regular index on this field as the search functionality is again supposed to encompass multiple fields. What I'd really like to do is specify that I don't want my search string to be tokenized/delimited. Is that possible? Are there other approaches?

Comment: [It does look like this has something to do with the text indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#tokenization-delimiters) - maybe try falling back to an older version of the text index?

Comment: @Bill we're experiencing the exact same thing, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Text indexes in mongo use delimiters and spaces, hyphen, dash are treated as delimiters. You can handle it from your program and pass the right text in your query to mongodb

[https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=JkBPDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA155&lpg=PA155&dq=Tokenization+Delimiters%2Bmongodb&source=bl&ots=OXjjadWjMD&sig=ACfU3U1U02DeKS-Gchx92f-hJ0HErCdCzA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHzo26s8rkAhUTgUsFHd2OAicQ6AEwDXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Tokenization%20Delimiters%2Bmongodb&f=false](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=JkBPDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA155&lpg=PA155&dq=Tokenization%20Delimiters%2Bmongodb&source=bl&ots=OXjjadWjMD&sig=ACfU3U1U02DeKS-Gchx92f-hJ0HErCdCzA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHzo26s8rkAhUTgUsFHd2OAicQ6AEwDXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Tokenization%20Delimiters%2Bmongodb&f=false)

OR

enclose the phrase in escaped double quotes:

`db.testsearch.find({"$text" : {"$search" : "\"a@b\""}})`

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to override what delimiters Mongo uses - if not on the index at least for the query. As stated above, enclosing the phrase in double quotes returns to the correct documents, but the query time is much much higher than a non-delimited search and you can see that in the query explanation it breaks up the terms despite the quotes.